# Implementing DSCP/QoS in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I've been working on implementing a webRTC solution for the past 6 months or so at my place of employ. We've got it working with the very little issue using web sockets with a node.js backend and Chrome as our browser of choice.

However, as we are starting to roll it out to more users the decision was made that we can't do so without tagging our webRTC traffic for our QoS. Upon doing a fair bit of reading on the subject and finding the following [blog post](http://gingertech.net/2014/03/19/apprtc-googles-webrtc-test-app-and-its-parameters/) explaining how to enable DSCP on google's own implementation, I attempted to enable DSCP in mine.

Adding 'googDSCP' as an optional constraint. This didn't seem to actually tag the traffic at all. Upon doing a Wireshark session, I found the method in the blog post of enabling tagging in the Google sample implementation didn't tag it either.

Looking for some help getting this working or understanding whether or not this is fully implemented. Sample code:

```
  rtc.dataChannelConfig = {
    "optional": [{
      "RtpDataChannels": true
    }, {
      "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true
    }, {
        "googDscp": true
    }]
  };
```

This is the config that gets passed along when I create the new PeerConnection object. When I look at the webrtc internals page in chrome the googDscp is definitely being set as 'true'. I've also tried to set them as mandatory instead of optional and had no better luck.

Comment: You running as admin? On a windows machine this option cannot be enabled unless running with admin privileges. Also, it does not seem that QoS is [fully implemented in Chrome yet](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2197&q=dscp&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: I found that discussions post as well. I wasn't 100% sure if that meant it hadn't been fully implemented or not.

I've tried it on PCs with and without admin privileges, doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: I see that you posted to the webrtc forum as well. I would rely on them as that discussion in the issue tracker is pretty vague.

Comment: Seems this is implemented for POSIX systems, but not Windows per this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277022)

Comment: Well, there you go :)